# Laravel error parsing header X-XSS-Protection

Tags: laravel, http-headers

I am developing a laravel 5.0 project. I don't know when or how this error occurs.

> Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: â1;mode=blockâ: expected 0
>   or 1 at character position 0. The default protections will be applied.

Specific in Developer > Network

> X-XSS-Protection:%E2%80%9C1;mode=block%E2%80%9D

The above error shows up in console. I've read about what this means and what X-XSS-Protection is but i have no idea what should i do to fix it (because i don't even know how this error occurs) . Please feel free ask for code blocks or files and i will provide. From what i understand laravel has it's own default security which are used in http headers but i have never searched about this topic. Is there a specific file where laravel configures the http headers?

Here is my `.htaccess` file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

**EDIT 1** :

(I have never edit this file)

What i found after searching `X-XSS-Protection` : (look at the last array)

In `vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Tests\ResponseHeaderBagTest.php`

```
   public function provideAllPreserveCase()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                array('fOo' => 'BAR'),
                array('fOo' => array('BAR'), 'Cache-Control' => array('no-cache')),
            ),
            array(
                array('ETag' => 'xyzzy'),
                array('ETag' => array('xyzzy'), 'Cache-Control' => array('private, must-revalidate')),
            ),
            array(
                array('Content-MD5' => 'Q2hlY2sgSW50ZWdyaXR5IQ=='),
                array('Content-MD5' => array('Q2hlY2sgSW50ZWdyaXR5IQ=='), 'Cache-Control' => array('no-cache')),
            ),
            array(
                array('P3P' => 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"'),
                array('P3P' => array('CP="CAO PSA OUR"'), 'Cache-Control' => array('no-cache')),
            ),
            array(
                array('WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic realm="WallyWorld"'),
                array('WWW-Authenticate' => array('Basic realm="WallyWorld"'), 'Cache-Control' => array('no-cache')),
            ),
            array(
                array('X-UA-Compatible' => 'IE=edge,chrome=1'),
                array('X-UA-Compatible' => array('IE=edge,chrome=1'), 'Cache-Control' => array('no-cache')),
            ),
            array(
                array('X-XSS-Protection' => '1; mode=block'),
                array('X-XSS-Protection' => array('1; mode=block'), 'Cache-Control' => array('no-cache')),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Comment: `X-XSS-Protection: â1;mode=blockâ` - that looks like a character encoding problem. As the message says, the value should start with 1 or 0 - but it doesn’t, since that weird `â` comes first ... Now the question is, what header does it try to parse here? I am not sure if that is about your own Laravel config (tried searching `X-XSS-Protection` across your code base?), or if that happens when trying to read content from a remote URL, that sends this faulty response header ...?

Comment: @CBroe updated question, please check